# Macbook is freezing and restarting again and again

Tags: performance

I am using a Macbook Pro 16 inch 2019 with macOS Big Sur version 11.2.3. My macbook randomly freezes mid screen and I can't move the cursor. Then it restarts all by itself with a whirring sound(probably made by the fans). It is very irritating as I have bought the laptop quite recently, hasn't downloaded any kind of malicious softwares and the storage left is also pretty decent. I can't understand the reason it freezes arbitrarily.Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Without further details as to when this is happening its going to be impossible to help. What are you doing before the crash? What programs are running? Is the computer under heavy load (check activity monitor)? Have you done an SMC reset, NVRAM/PRAM reset, booted into safe mode and created another user acc to check whether to problem persists(https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)? Do you have a backup so you could try a fresh macOS install? Some people here might also be able to help if you share the crash log.

Comment: You should take it back if its mis-behaving like this - Apple have diagnostics tools that can see a lot more than you can and should be able to see that there have been crashes / freezes.

Comment: @X_841 I have tried the SMC reset but the problem persists. Most of the times the laptop hangs when the LAN network goes down and I reconnect the Ethernet cable adapter to the laptop.

Comment: There are still plenty of suggestions you could try. Network interruptions should not affect a MacBook in that way unless there is maybe some program or website that has a bug.